# Conversation failed when converting the varchar to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a stored procedure and getting error:

> Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

Please anyone help me where I'm going wrong:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DBCR]
    @StartDate Date,
    @EndDate Date,
    @LicenseRequestID int,
    @CRNumber nvarchar(40),
    @StatusID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LRM.StatusID StatusID,
        CAST(CRI.CRNumber as nvarchar(40)) CRNumber,
        CRI.NAMEAR CompanyName,
        CRI.CityAR CityName,
        CRI.PhoneNumber,
        CRI.CreatedDate CRIDate,
        LRM.CreationDate LicenseRequestDate,
        LRM.ID LicenseRequestID,
        O.UserName OwerName, O.Email,
        C.Message,
        SD.NAME STATUS 
    FROM
        CR_Informations CRI
    LEFT JOIN 
        LicenseRequestMaster LRM ON LRM.CRNumber = CRI.CRNumber
    LEFT JOIN 
        [User] O ON O.ID = LRM.CRNUMBER
    LEFT JOIN 
        Comment C ON C.LicenseRequestID = LRM.ID AND O.ID = C.SenderID
    INNER JOIN 
        StatusDetail SD ON SD.StatusID = LRM.StatusID 
    WHERE 
        (@LicenseRequestID IS NULL OR LRM.ID = @LicenseRequestID + '%')
        AND (@CRNumber IS NULL OR CRI.CRNumber = @CRNumber + '%')
        AND (@StatusID IS NULL OR LRM.StatusID = @StatusID + '%')
        AND CRI.CreatedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
END;
```

Comment: According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) when you combine an `int` with a `varchar` in one expression, e.g. `@LicenseRequestID + '%'`, the `varchar` must be converted to an `int`. What is the numeric value of `'%'`?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing it is one of the expressions like this:

```
@LicenseRequestID + '%'
```

If the parameter is ever a number, this will treat the `+` as, well, addition.

Just use `concat()` instead:

```
concat(@LicenseRequestID, '%')
```

It converts everything to strings.

That is:

```
WHERE (@LicenseRequestID IS NULL OR
       LRM.ID LIKE CONCAT(@LicenseRequestID, '%')
      )
```

Comment: im looking for if paramter have null then its shoe me all records and if someone fill the paramter then show me only those values

Comment: @FG . . . You just use `CONCAT()` in the `WHERE` clause.  I provided an example.